# 3D CSS + floated elements - floats are above 3D transformations

Tags: css, 3d, css-float

I'm working on a little calendar thing, with 3D transforms/transitions on the dates. When you hover, they should open like a little door. I've got this much working perfectly.

Here's my issue: in the calendar, the dates from the next row overlap the little door effect. Basically, you can't see the bottom of the 3d effect. I made the overlapping `li`s translucent, so you can see that the bottom of the door *is* there, just obscured.

I don't think it's a z-index issue, but something with the floats. I'm totally open to positioning the calendar dates in an different way, but this is all I can think of for now.

Here's some jQuery that applies a descending z-index to the elements, but it doesn't do anything. Even if it did work, I have a feeling it would cut off the *top* of the door effect.

[Here's a jsFiddle the shows everything in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/HUGgZ/) Remember to use Safari or Chrome.

```
 $('.cal ul li').each(function(index) {
     var days = $('.cal ul').children('li').size();
     $(this).css('z-index',days - index);
 });
```

Thanks! I hope I'm not getting ahead of myself with what 3D css transforms are capable of.

**Edit**

OK, I think I've got it. I adjusted the z-index on `li:hover` (the days), and that ensures that it'll be in the foreground. I ran into an issue with the borders of the `li`s being on top of the content.

To get around this, I adjusted it so there's a transition on the `li`, but not the `li:hover`. This way, there's a transition *back* to 2D, but not one when the 3D effect happens. The only thing being adjusted on the `li:hover` is the z-index. The actual 3D happens on the `a` inside of the `li`, so as long as the door closing effect is shorter than the z-index change, the border won't be visible through the door.

Here's [an updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HUGgZ/2/) that shows everything. Please let me know if you spot any way to improve this further.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `position:relative` along with the `z-index`